# how to limit the text been pasted via mouse click in a textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, char, textarea

we have a **textarea** and it should allow only 300 char's. we are able to control it via any **keyboard press event** using

```
onkeydown="limitText(this,300);" 
onkeyup="limitText(this,300);
```

where `limitText` is as follows

```
limitText = function (limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
},
```

But we are unable to control **mouseClick** paste via this....Please share any idea on this.
Please Note: i checked few solutions on internet but couldnt solve. i know its a small issue, but as am new to **jQuery** (infact to the whole web world), am unable to ping at the right place.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle all input modern browsers have [`oninput` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.oninput)

Here the sample that do what you asked using this event:

```
$('.limited').bind('input',function() {
    var $t=$(this);
    var max=$t.data('maxchars');
if ($t.val().length>max) {
    $t.val($t.val().substr(0,max));
}
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rR7Qd/)

for old browsers you should use keyup,keydown+onpaste:

```
$('.limited').bind('keyup keydown paste',function(e) {
    var $t=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    var max=$t.data('maxchars');
if ($t.val().length>max) {
    $t.val($t.val().substr(0,max));
}
    },0);
});​
```

[OLD BROWSERS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rR7Qd/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Controlling the length of a textarea via javascript is not really a smart solution as HTML already supports that out of the box :)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

```
<textarea maxlength="50">
  Enter text here...
</textarea>
```

I'm not 100% sure if this an old feature or was invented by HTML5. Imho it was already available since some revisions. But w3schools says its new for textareas.

PS: Here is something I wrote some month ago: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery.char-counter. It's basically observing the number of chars inserted into a textarea and cutting off everything that is too much. Also you get a char counter.

PPS: A demo of jquery.char-counter: http://jsfiddle.net/TBDue/

Comment: [MDN textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea#Compatibility) seems maxlength not supported in IE at all

Comment: Those suckers :D So my jquery plugin isn't as useless as I thought :)